# UWP x:bind issue - Invalid binding path 'dpl' : Property 'dpl' not found on type 'DataTemplate'

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

I have a class `PricingData` and `PricingSchedule`.  Where `PricingSchedule` is a List<> inside `PricingData` class. I want to bind data of this class to UWP controls.

Sample code is available to download here : https://github.com/jigneshdesai/SampleOfBindingIssue1.git

**How Code looks:**  i have a start page(mainpage) that hosts ListView control, Listview has PricingUserControl within it. PricingUserControl looks like this

```
<TextBlock x:Name="lblPriceHeader" Text="{Binding PricingTitle}" Margin="0,0,50,0" />
            <ComboBox  x:Name="cbPriceValueList" ItemsSource="{x:Bind dpl}" DisplayMemberPath="PriceValue" SelectedValuePath="PriceValue"  SelectedValue="{Binding DisplayPricing}"   />

            <ListView x:Name="lbPriceChangeSchedule" ItemsSource="{Binding PricingScheduleList}">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <ComboBox  x:Name="cbSchedulePriceValueList"  ItemsSource="{x:Bind dpl}" DisplayMemberPath="PriceValue" SelectedValuePath="PriceValue"  />

                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding SchedulePricingTimeZone }" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
```

**What i want to achieve**: Combobox should populate a list of values (eg. 1USD, 2USD, 3USD etc.). Then when you provide List of records from database,  the listbox will repeat PricingUserControl  and combobox within it should set its value property (SelectedValue) as per record.

***Issue***: 
ComboBox  x:Name="cbPriceValueList" uses **x:bind dpl** where dpl is a local variable of PricingUserControl. It populates the list properly.  The trouble is ComboBox  x:Name="cbSchedulePriceValueList" it also has  **x:bind dpl**  but during compilation it display error ***"Invalid binding path 'dpl' : Property 'dpl' not found on type 'DataTemplate'."***

I am wondering why x:bind dpl does not work at this point. ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have now realized that your problem is in fact that you need to reach to a `Page` property from within the `DataTemplate`, so here is a updated answer.

You cannot use `x:Bind` if you need to access an outside element's property from within a `DataTemplate`. Instead, you can use classic `{Binding}` expression. First add a name to your page:

```
<Page
   ...
   x:Name="Page">
```

And now refer to this name from within the `DataTemplate`:

```
<ComboBox  
     x:Name="cbSchedulePriceValueList"  
     ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=Page, Path=dpl}" 
     DisplayMemberPath="PriceValue" 
     SelectedValuePath="PriceValue"  />
```

## Original answer

To be able to use `x:Bind` inside of a `DataTemplate`, you must specify the data type the individual items of the control will have, using `x:DataType`. Suppose your `PricingScheduleList` is a `List<MyApp.Models.MyType>`, then you will first need to add this XML namespace to the `<Page>` element:

```
xmlns:models="using:MyApp.Models"
```

And then set the `x:DataType` attribute as follows:

```
<DataTemplate x:DataType="models:MyType">
    ...
</DataTemplate>
```

You can confirm this works by the fact that IntelliSense should now suggest you the properties of `MyType` when you start writing the `x:Bind` expression.

Comment: Hi Martin Zikmund, I have updated the sourcecode at GitHub url with your suggestion ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=UCpage, Path=dpl}"  but it still does populate combox with list of values.  Can you please have a look and guide.

Comment: When I checked your latest project, the comboBox named "cbSchedulePriceValueList" could successfully display the list of values, it worked well, so what is your current issue, can you show more details about this?

Comment: Hi Faywang,
I updated the code, perhaps you have seen latest commit, but if you check previous commit, it not working as suggested by Martin Z. 

In latest comments it works beause i have modified code in a different way. I created a resource
<UserControl.Resources>
        <local:cdpl x:Name="myList" x:Key="myList"></local:cdpl>
</UserControl.Resources>
and that used that in the binding x:Name="cbSchedulePriceValueList" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource myList}}".   This approach worked.

Comment: But still the problem is that non of below two statements work
 SelectedItem="{Binding DisplayPricing,Mode=TwoWay}"  SelectedValue="{Binding DisplayPricing,Mode=TwoWay}"

Can you put some light on it?

Answer (score 2):

By checking your code, the reason why SelectedValue does not take effect is when you choose the item from ComboBox, you didn't notify your DisplayPricing to change. So you need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged interface in your PricingData. Do the same behavior in PricingSchedule.

```
public class PricingData : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };
        ......

        public string DisplayPricing
        {
            get => $"{PricingValue} {PricingCurrency}";
            set
            {
                var sp = value.Split(' ');
                PricingValue = sp.First();
                PricingCurrency = sp.Last();
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

PScheduleUserControl.xaml:

```
<ComboBox  x:Name="cbPriceValueList" ItemsSource="{x:Bind myList}" DisplayMemberPath="PriceValue" SelectedValuePath="PriceValue"  SelectedValue="{Binding DisplayPricing,Mode=TwoWay}" />
```